# Error in data type in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file which has 4 attributes like this:

```
    taxi id     date time   longitude   latitude
0   1   2008-02-02 15:36:08     116.51172   39.92123
1   1   2008-02-02 15:46:08     116.51135   39.93883
2   1   2008-02-02 15:46:08     116.51135   39.93883
3   1   2008-02-02 15:56:08     116.51627   39.91034
4   1   2008-02-02 16:06:08     116.47186   39.91248
```

I have read this file in jupyter by using this command:

```
res=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/malik/Desktop/result.txt",low_memory=False)
res.head()
```

but when i want to fetch out the datatype of attributes by using this code:

```
type(res)
res['longitude'].dtype
```

It gives me error like:

> KeyError: 'longitude'

Comment: make sure your column is actually called `longitude`, there could be some unexpected whitespaces in the column names. You can check the actual column names via `res.columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your column names are not quite as expected. Make sure they are exact matches (no extra whitespace or anything) by explicitely naming them after loading your dataframe:

```
res.columns = ['taxi id', 'date time', 'longitude', 'latitude']
```

and then trying `res['longitude'].dtype`

Alternatively, set the column names as you load the data using the `names` argument to `pd.read_csv` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html))

```
res=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/malik/Desktop/result.txt", names = ['taxi id', 'date time', 'longitude', 'latitude'], low_memory=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data ingestion is incorrect.  You have a table with *one* column named
`taxi id     date time   longitude   latitude`.  You need to insert or specify the proper data separator when your read the file.